# How to add multiple model evaluation parameters in lattice plot?

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to automatically add multiple model evaluation parameters in `lattice` plot. I am using the following code

```
library(lattice)
library(tidyverse)
library(hydroGOF)

#Calculation of model evaluation parameters
summ <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Rsq = cor(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)^2,
            RMSE = RMSE(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length),
            NSE = NSE(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits=2)

#Make multipanel plot 
xyplot(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length | Species, data = iris, pch = 23, 
       layout=c(3,1), type = c("p", "r"),
       scales=list(cex=c(1.4,1.4), alternating=1, relation = "free"),
       xlab = list(label="Sepal Length", fontsize=20),
       ylab = list(label="Petal Length", fontsize=20))
```

which gives me the following plot
[image]

Now how can I have the following plot using `lattice` package
[image]

**Edit**

While adding `panel.lmbands` from mosaic `package` to solutions (1) and (3) works but I was unable to achieve it using solution (2). Here is the code

```
library(mosaic)
p2 <- xyplot(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length | Species, data = iris, pch = 23, 
             layout=c(3,1), 
             band.lty = c(conf =2, pred = 1), 
             band.lwd =c(conf =1, pred = 1),
             npts = 500,
             panel = panel.lmbands,
             scales=list(cex=c(1.4,1.4), alternating=1, relation = "free"),
             xlab = list(label="Sepal Length", fontsize=20),
             ylab = list(label="Petal Length", fontsize=20),
             panel = function(x, ...) {
               i <- panel.number()
               panel.xyplot(x, ...)
               panel.key(as.expression(summ$ann[[i]]), points = FALSE)
             })
p2
```

It returns me following error

> Error in xyplot.formula(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length | Species, data = iris,  :
> formal argument "panel" matched by multiple actual arguments

The expected output will look like the following

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three approaches with lattice. `summ` is calculated in (1) as in the question except `RMSE` is `rmse` in hydroGOF and we add an `ann` column which contains the annotations.  `summ` is also used in (2) and (3). `p` in (1) uses the same code as in the question and it is used again without change in (3).  All use `panel.key` from latticeExtra and (3) also uses `layer` from latticeExtra.

**1) trellis.focus**  We can use `trellis.focus/trellis.unfocus` to modify panels after the fact.

```
library(latticeExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(hydroGOF)

#Calculation of model evaluation parameters
summ <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(Rsq = cor(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)^2,
            RMSE = rmse(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length),
            NSE = NSE(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits=2)

summ$ann <- lapply(1:nrow(summ), function(i) with(summ[i, ], 
  c(bquote(R^2 == .(Rsq)), bquote(RMSE == .(RMSE)), bquote(NSE == .(NSE))))
)

#Make multipanel plot 
p <- xyplot(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length | Species, data = iris, pch = 23, 
       layout=c(3,1), type = c("p", "r"),
       scales=list(cex=c(1.4,1.4), alternating=1, relation = "free"),
       xlab = list(label="Sepal Length", fontsize=20),
       ylab = list(label="Petal Length", fontsize=20))
p
for(i in 1:nrow(summ)) {
  trellis.focus("panel", i, 1)
  pno <- panel.number()
  panel.key(as.expression(summ$ann[[i]]), points = FALSE)
  trellis.unfocus()
}
```

**2) panel function**  We define the indicated panel function which makes use of `panel.number()` to draw the correct text.

```
p2 <- xyplot(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length | Species, data = iris, pch = 23, 
       layout=c(3,1), type = c("p", "r"),
       scales=list(cex=c(1.4,1.4), alternating=1, relation = "free"),
       xlab = list(label="Sepal Length", fontsize=20),
       ylab = list(label="Petal Length", fontsize=20),
       panel = function(x, ...) {
         i <- panel.number()
         panel.xyplot(x, ...)
         panel.key(as.expression(summ$ann[[i]]), points = FALSE)
       })
p2
```

**3) latticeExtra::layer**  Layers using `layer` in latticeExtra allow one to add layers to a lattice plot using `+` in a similar way that is done in ggplot2.

```
p3 <- p
for(i in 1:nrow(summ)) {
  p3 <- p3 + 
    layer(panel.key(as.expression(ann), points = FALSE), 
      data = list(ann = summ$ann[[i]]), packets = i)
}
p3
```

Any of the above give this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How can we remove the dots after R2, RMSE and NSE? and another thing how can we add `panel.lmbands` from `mosaic` package?

Comment: Updated answer to remove points.  You can add additional panel.* commands before or after panel.key in solutions (1) and (2) and can add an extra layer(...) command to (3).  You will need to ensure that you actually have access to whatever data you are using.

Comment: I could able to add `panel.lmbands` to solutions (1) and (3) but was unable to achieve it using solution (2). Can you please see to it?

Comment: Please provide your successful code in a reproducible manner for (1) and (3) so it is clear what you are referring to.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please see to it. Thank you very much for a detailed solution.

Comment: You can't have two arguments to a function with the same name.                 `panel.lmbands(x, ...);` needs to be added just before `panel.key(x, ...)` or just after it within the existing panel function.

Comment: I have tried to add it within the existing panel function. It is not working. Can you please see it?

Comment: Maybe you didn't follow the instructions in my comment exactly as it works for me.

Comment: Can you please update your answer by adding `panel.lmbands` part? Sorry for bothering you again and again.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck This might be a silly question but R2 is the same as the Pearson correlation?

Comment: In linear regression R squared is numerically equal to the square of the correlation between the dependent variable and the fitted values.  For example, in 
`fm <- lm(demand ~ Time, BOD)`
`summary(fm)$r.squared` equals `cor(BOD$demand, fitted(fm))^2`